# Nativescript: how to programmatically disable / enable ScrollView scrolling?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Is there a way to programatically disable/enable ScrollView scrolling in NativeScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do that. It's actually pretty easy on iOS:

```
var scrollView = page.getViewById('YOUR_VIEW_ID')
scrollView.ios.scrollEnabled = false // to disable
scrollView.ios.scrollEnabled = true  // to enable back
```

Android:

Also for my particular case, where I need to disable scrolling of the Scroll View, but drag and drop child views inside. On subview start dragging (panning) event we prevent touch events interception in our Scroll View by:

```
scrollView._nativeView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
```

And enable them again on stop dragging (panning) subview event by:

```
scrollView._nativeView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
```

If you have another case and just want to disable Scroll View scrolling you can use something like this (for Android):

```
scrollView._nativeView.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener({
   onTouch: function (view, motionEvent) {
       console.log("DISABLED. onTouch event: Got    motionEvent.getAction() " + motionEvent.getAction() + ".");
       return true;
    }
}))
```

Comment: `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` doesn't seem to be working for me, has this been tested on latest version of NativeScript?

Comment: `scrollView.ios.scrollEnabled = false` Thank you! One-liner works for me.

Comment: The block of code where you use `setOnTouchListener` worked for me. Keep in mind that you have to declare android first, so that'd be `declare const android: any;`.

Answer (score 4):

#### iOS

```js
scroll_view.ios.scrollEnabled = false; // Disables user scrolling.
scroll_view.ios.scrollEnabled = true; // Enables user scrolling.
```

#### Android

```js
scroll_view.android.setScrollEnabled(false); // Disables user scrolling.
scroll_view.android.setScrollEnabled(true); // Enables user scrolling.
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 Version:

In your html:

```
<ScrollView #scrollView >
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

In your controller:

```
@ViewChild('scrollView') scrollView: ElementRef;

allowScrolling(e) {
    const scrollView: ScrollView = this.scrollView.nativeElement;
    if (platformModule.device.os === 'Android') {
        scrollView.nativeView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
    if (platformModule.device.os === 'iOS') {
        scrollView.ios.scrollEnabled = !e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for this, you can set `isUserInteractionEnabled`  to `false` in the `ScrollView` element and it will disable the user scrolling (you can still do it programmatically).

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2892#issuecomment-253536941

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to disable **ScrollView** scrolling in **NativeScript**. In case you want to use **ScrollView** as a container, you can use ContentView for this purpose . However could you give me more info, why do you want to disable the scrolling.

Comment: Well, I have draggable elements inside ScrollView. When I drag them down ScrollView is scrolling to. I would like to disable the ScrollView once pan 'began' event is fired and activate it back once I register pan 'ended'.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
this.scrollview.isUserInteractionEnabled=false;
```

or this

```
this.scrollView.nativeElement).android.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

for android