# Nativescript - Disable scrollview scroll

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

first of all thanks for your attention about this thread.

Here is my problem : 
I have a Google map inside a ScrollView layout. Everything is working fine on iOS, the ScrollView scrolls and the map is fully usable.

However on android, when a touch event is raised from the map, the scroll view's gesture events will trigger first and will dismiss the map one.
Thus it is impossible to use the map inside the scroll view.

To solve this problem, I thought to simply disable the scrollview's event so the map's one could be handled. After many searches I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773101/nativescript-how-to-programmatically-disable-enable-scrollview-scrolling) which could do the trick, but has simply no effect.

There is my code :

```
@ViewChild("mainScrollView") mainScrollView : ElementRef;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.disableScrollView()
}

private disableScrollView(){

    const scrollView: ScrollView = this.mainScrollView.nativeElement;

    console.log("scroll view :")
    console.dir(scrollView)

    if (isAndroid) {
        console.log("is Android")
        scrollView.android.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}
```

More globally, I know this problem affects every layout having gestures inside a ScrollView.
So it would be great to have a workaround fixing this problem !

PS : My project is working on Nativescript 3.3.0 with Angular.

Comment: If you don't need the scrolling, why not just remove the ScrollView layout at all?

Comment: I am switching between three types of content in the scroll container, two which are a list of items, and the third is the map (such a kind of a tab view).
So I need to scroll on the lists, but not especially on the map.
I say not especially, because on my ui, the scroll container is not taking the full height of the screen when the view is opened. There are some other content above, and then user can scroll over. That's why it would be better if I could scroll.
Anyway, I absolutely need to keep my map inside the scrollview otherwise it would break my display.